# Is it possible to fill both depth buffer and color buffer within a MRT context using OpenGL and GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Here's my situation:

I've written a small deferred 3D engine using MRT (Multi Render Target) to fill my G-Buffer (all my position, normal, color and specular textures are filled at the same time).

In addition I've attached to my G-Buffer FBO a Render Buffer Object (RBO) initialized as GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT (GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8). So during the G-Buffer execution my 4 textures are filled simultaneously and the render buffer fills at the same time the stencil and the depth buffer.

I have 2 questions:

- Is it possible to use for any reasons THIS depth buffer as a sampler2D uniform variable within a fragment shader for example I could use to compute something during the lighting pass (for instance, recover vertex position in view-space from depth)? It would be a gain of time to use this depth buffer directly!

If it's not possible :

- Is it possible to fill a depth texture (GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT format) within a MRT? For example, is it possible to fill a depth texture and a color texture using MRT rendering technique ? (I tried without any success but maybe I got caught badly). Do I need to fill my color buffer using MRT, and the depth buffer separatly (two render passes are needed here instead of one)?

If it's not possible again what do you advice me ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: What problem did you get exactly? Did manage to create a texture with a depth(+stencil) internal format and attach it to the depth(+stencil) attachment points of your FBO? Then did you manage to use that texture normally in a shader (bind into a TU and sample using a `sampler2D` using the ordinary `texture(depthSampler, coordinates);` call)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use for any reasons THIS depth buffer as a sampler2D
>   uniform variable within a fragment shader for example I could use to
>   compute something during the lighting pass (for instance, recover
>   vertex position in view-space from depth)? It would be a gain of time
>   to use this depth buffer directly!

Yes, depth buffers can be samplers in a fragment shader and are accessed with the typical `texture(depthTexture,...)` command.

In a typical deferred rendering path you first write the gBuffer (the depth buffer is part of the gBuffer) and then you bind all gBuffer textures to samplers and use them while lighting calculations.

If you mean with 'THIS' depth buffer that you want to sample the currently used depth buffer you're writing into, then that is not possible. A texture can not be written and read at the same time (OpenGL ES might be an exception here).

> Is it possible to fill a depth texture (GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT format)
>   within a MRT? For example, is it possible to fill a depth texture and
>   a color texture using MRT rendering technique ? (I tried without any
>   success but maybe I got caught badly). Do I need to fill my color
>   buffer using MRT, and the depth buffer separatly (two render passes
>   are needed here instead of one)?

Yes as i said above, that is the typical way. Just attach the depth texture to the depth part of the framebuffer (or if it's a depth+stencil texture attach it to the depth+stencil part  of the framebuffer). See https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/docbook4/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture.xml

**Update**

I'm sorry, I somehow didn't read, that you're talking about RBOs.

No, the depth buffer of a RBO, can **not** be bound to a texture sampler (since it's not a texture). There are 2 ways to solve this problem:

- Use a FBO instead of a RBO with a depth texture attached to it. (recommended)
- Copy the data of the RBO to a depth texture. If you really want to do that, there are again 2 possible ways:

  - Create a FBO with only a depth texture attached to it and copy the RBO to that texture with `glBlitFramebuffers` see: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml
  - Copy the depth buffer to the CPU with `glReadPixel` and then copy it back to your depth texture. (The FBO approach is of course recommended, since it would be a GPU->GPU transfer.)

Comment: What do you mean by "A texture can not be written and read at the same time". I know it's not possible and in my case I don't do that. During the material pass I write data to my g-buffer (the depth texture is filled from the RBO) and I read the G-Buffer during the lighting pass. My question is: Is it possible to bind (using glBindTexture) the depth buffer during the lighting pass like it's the case for other color buffers -> normal, color, specular used as samplers in my lighting pixel shader) -> I mean the depth buffer filled using the RBO NOT a seperate depth buffer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In other words is it possible to access to the depth buffer from the render buffer by binding ? I don't think so but I'm not sure about this! For me I think there are 2 ways to store depth information and use it in lighting pass by texture binding : render in a separate pass into a classical depth texture OR store the depth information into a color buffer (rgb) this time within a MRT context! I What do you think about this ?

Comment: Actually, I use a RBO attached to my FBO.for depth tests (determine the closest surface at each pixel) and I use stencil buffer to target the usage of fragment shaders(G-Buffer{position, normal, color, specular + {RBO{depth, stencil}}}). So your first solution will be good but I will lost the stencil buffer usage. I know the only way using a stencil buffer throw a FBO is to attach a RBO GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 to it. That's why I suggest to keep the RBO usage to depth testing and stencil operations and use a color texture to store depth information. What do you think about that?

Comment: I found this tutorial http://gamedevs.org/uploads/deferred-shading-tutorial.pdf. Look at from page 12 concerning the material pass. Thanks again for your feed back!

Comment: `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` is a valid texture format and can directly be attached to a FBO with `glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT,textureId,0)` .https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Depth_stencil_formats